# Delete scheduled message from telegram using telethon library

Tags: python, telegram, message, schedule, telethon

I am almost new to telegram bots development and have basic experience in using the telethon python library.
I am working on a project where I need to schedule the message using telethon and then delete the messages if needed. I am using following code to schedule the messages on telegram channels and groups.

```
await client.send_message(receiver, message_text, schedule=schedule_time)
```

And when I need to get the scheduled messages for that channels I am using the following code to get the messages from the telegram servers.

```
result = await self.client(functions.messages.GetScheduledHistoryRequest(
        peer=target,
        hash=0
    ))
```

And I want to delete the messages I have scheduled. I have gone through the documentation of telethon library and found the following code to do delete the messages.

```
    group = await client.get_entity(group_id)
    list_of_messages = await get_scheduled_messages(group_id)
    for message in list_of_messages:
        status = await client.delete_messages(group, [message.id])
```

And this is not working. I have also tried the delete method for the message object like this.

```
 group = await client.get_entity(group_id)
 list_of_messages = await get_scheduled_messages(group_id)
 for message in list_of_messages:
        await message.delete()
```

Is there something I am missing or there is nothing to delete the scheduled messages which has not been sen yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete your scheduled messages you'll have first to get them using [`GetScheduledHistoryRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_scheduled_history.html) and then you can delete all the messages you'd prefer to, using [`DeleteScheduledMessagesRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/delete_scheduled_messages.html).

```
chat = await client.get_input_entity('yourchat')
result = await client(functions.messages.GetScheduledHistoryRequest(
     peer=chat,
     hash=0
))
# use result.messages to access the list of scheduled messages
msg = result.messages[0] # or any other message you want to delete
await client(functions.messages.DeleteScheduledMessagesRequest(
    peer=chat,
    id=[msg.id] # !imporant you need to pass a list here
))
```

In order to edit a scheduled message, since the `edit_messages()` and `edit()` functions seems not working properly with scheduled messages, you'll need to use the Telegram raw APIs [messages.editMessage](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.editMessage).

```
chat = await client.get_input_entity('yourchat')
result = await client(functions.messages.GetScheduledHistoryRequest(
     peer=chat,
     hash=0
     ))
msg = result.messages[0] # or any other message you want to edit
await client(functions.messages.EditMessageRequest(
   peer = msg.to_id,
   id = msg.id,
   message = 'new text',
   no_webpage= False, # didn't find anything into the Message object to refer to
   entities= msg.entities,
   media= msg.media,
   reply_markup = msg.reply_markup,
   schedule_date= msg.date
))
```

Keep in mind that I've refer to the older message to fill the all parameters into the `EditMessageRequest()` function, but you should be able to edit `no_webpage`, `media`, `schedule_date` without any problem.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much. I just never found that method.
Can you tell me if there is any method for editing scheduled messages?